# cannot allocate object of abstract type - but the class is not abstract! (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm doing a Systems Programming homework.
I have to implement a university.
I have a Course class, with child classes ComputerScience courses class, PG courses class, and Elective courses class.

```
class Course
{
public:
    virtual void teach();
    virtual void reg(Student &s)=0;
    std::string getName();
    std::string getDepartment();
    int getSemester();
    int getMinGrade();
    void addStudent(Student *s);
    void removeStudent(Student *s);

protected:
    std::string _department;
    std::string _name;
    int _semester;
    int _minGrade;
    std::vector<Student*> studentsList;  
};

class CSCourse : public Course
{
public:
    CSCourse();
    CSCourse(std::string department, std::string name, int semester, int mingrade);
    ~CSCourse();
    std::string getName();
    std::string getDepartment();
    int getSemester();
    int getMinGrade();
    void addStudent(Student *s);
    void removeStudent(Student *s);
};
```

(PG courses and Elective courses child classes are the same)
In the functions in the Course class (which are not void, like getSemester and such..) I just do dynamic_cast to figure what type of course is it.

I am having this problem:

coursesVector is:

```
std::vector<Course*> coursesVector
```

and dp variable is a string containing either CS, PG or Elective. In the main, I do this:

```
if (dp == "CS")
{
    CSCourse *csCourse = new CSCourse(dp, name, semester, minGrade);
    coursesVector.push_back(csCourse);
}
```

it gives me "Cannot allocate object of abstract type CS Course".
Same goes for PG and Elective!

But, in my definiton of hte class, CS course is not abstract!

Comment: as a side-note: create a virtual destructor in the base class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `CSCourse` class *is* abstract.

You have declared a pure virtual function `reg` in `Course`, but not provided an implementation in `CSCourse`.

You compiler undoubtedly told you exactly this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're inheriting from an abstract class which is fine, but you are never implementing the pure virtual function that the base class defines.

Also you need a virtual destructor in your base class;)

Edit:
You're also doing other things that probably aren't necessary like redeclaring most of your derived class functions.  I bet their implementation is the exact same as your base class?

Answer (score 1):

You have not implemented the pure virtual function `reg` in your derived class:

`virtual void reg(Student &s)=0;`

So yes, your class is abstract.